# Select HTML5 JSON AJAX JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html

I want to make an html5 select with data given by javascript, and inside this javascript an ajax calling a Json URL. I mean, I´ve got this:

--index.html

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="functions_app.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getData()">

<p>Sessions: 
<select id="Select"></select>


</body>
</html>
```

functions_apps.js

```js
function getData(){

     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://.../json_offers.php', 

      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
       //alert(data);
       $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
        var id = "";
           var name = "";
           
      $.each(registro, function(key, value) {
       //alert(campo + ": " + valor);
       if (key == "id") { id = value; }
       if (key == "name") { name = value; }
              
      });
                 }); 
   $("#select").append('<option value='+id+'>'+nombre+'</option>');   
      },
      error: function(data) {
       alert('error');
      }
     });
}
```

json_offers.php

```js
Json data:
[{"id":"6","name":"FLOWERS"},{"id":"8","name":"GROCERY"}]
```

But It does not work. It always return:

**error: function(data)**

I can´t load data given inside html select.

Any Help?

Best Regards

Comment: It does not work... how? You need to include some specifics, the error message, anything.

Comment: si quieres publicarlo en español: http://es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You have `<select id="Select"></select>`, but you are trying to put options into `$("#select_zcas")`